# Customize embedded google maps (adding location marks)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to add location details in google maps for a company, I'm using this code at the moment to embed the map location in the website:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="550" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=26.180782,50.509&amp;spn=0.018486,0.027466&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Here's an image of where I want to mark the map:

http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/7789/jm8i.png

In maps.google.com I tried using the my places > create map option, which worked, but embedding it also showed edit menu (layer options..etc) and I couldn't adjust the zoom level so it didn't work out the way I wanted it to, I want it to look simply like the image with a mark added.

AFAIK you can officially add your company's details on google maps, but that needs verification which could take 2+ weeks and the company owner is kind of in a hurry to launch the website so I needed a quick solution for now.

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: http://mapsengine.google.com ? Provides what you want I think.

Comment: I have a project on GitHub that may suit your needs.  Your welcome to fork.  https://github.com/dreamcc/google-world-map?files=1

Answer (score 2):

You might try http://www.embed-google-map.com/. This is what I used to generate an embedded iframe map for a website.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the URL in your `iframe`:

```
https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=26.180782,50.509&amp;spn=0.018486,0.027466&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed
```

and change the `ll=` to `daddr=`, this will sets the end point for directions searches to the coordinates following the `=`.

So your `iframe` code is now:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="550" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;daddr=26.180782,50.509&amp;spn=0.018486,0.027466&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WbEA3/)

This adds the standard green marker to your map. It seems like the coordinates are slightly wrong (see image below) but hopefully this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google static maps sound like your best option. Full documentation can be found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/. 
You don't need an iframe. Simply use an `img` tag with the appropriate "src" value.
Heres the src you need:
 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=`YOUR LAT AND LONG SEPERATED BY COMMA`&zoom=`DESIRED ZOOM LEVEL`&size=`DESIRED DIMENSIONS`&markers=color:red%7C`YOUR LAT AND LONG AGAIN`&sensor=false

Example:

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=26.178019,50.509642&zoom=15&size=600x300&markers=color:red%7C26.178019,50.509642&sensor=false" alt="">
```

[image]